# Nginx: 403 on static files (port 80 only)

Tags: nginx

When on a higher port, say 8000, my static files are loaded fine. When I run the server on port 80 (using sudo), I get 403 errors. Any idea why this would be?

My only thought is that its something to do with running as root, the file permissions are all normal, even going -777- doesn't change the error.

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http{
    upstream django {
    server 127.0.0.1:8001;
    }
# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      80;

    root ~/my/path/;

    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 127.0.0.1;
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias _;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        root /my/path/static/;
    }

    location ~ \.css {
        root /my/path/static/;
    }

    location ~ \.js {
        root /my/path/static/;
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include    ../uwsgi_params; 
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to share your nginx config file.
Also, check the nginx error log for a hint as to why it's throwing 403's. Usually `/var/log/nginx/error`

Comment: ill add the config, the error just says `permission denied` in the log. im confused why it would throw that only for port 80, and i feel it has something to do with running nginx as root.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this context to your content directory:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /my/path/static
```

Or you need to disable Selinux.
Edit `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` file to disable selinux permanently.
`setenforce 0` to disable selinux on-the-fly.